# How to parse this json data in Delphi 10 Seattle?

Tags: json, delphi

I am having trouble parsing this JSON data in Delphi 10 Seattle. I want to get the values from the JSON and show them in `TLabel` components one by one. I am new to JSON and REST, it would be nice if you provide a working example.

```json
{
  "countrydata":[
    {
      "info":{
        "ourid":119,
        "title":"Pakistan",
        "code":"PK",
        "source":"https://thevirustracker.com/pakistan-coronavirus-information-pk"
      },
      "total_cases":5038,
      "total_recovered":1026,
      "total_unresolved":0,
      "total_deaths":86,
      "total_new_cases_today":27,
      "total_new_deaths_today":0,
      "total_active_cases":3926,
      "total_serious_cases":37,
      "total_danger_rank":33
    }
  ],
  "stat":"ok"
}
```

**EDIT**
So far, I have this code but it gives access violation error and no output is given. What am I doing wrong.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  jsonRoot: TJSONObject;
  tokenRequest: TRESTRequest;
  tokenResponse: TRESTResponse;
  tokenClient: TRESTClient;
begin
  tokenClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  tokenRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  tokenResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
  try
    tokenRequest.Client := tokenClient;
    tokenRequest.Response := tokenResponse;
    tokenClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=PK';
    tokenRequest.Execute;
    jsonRoot:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(tokenResponse.JSONText) as TJSONObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalCases => ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('total_cases').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalRecovered=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('total_recovered').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalDeaths=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('total_deaths').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotoalNewCases=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('total_new_cases_today').Value);
  finally
    tokenResponse.Free;
    tokenRequest.Free;
    tokenClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. What have you attempted so far that is not working for you?  What does your code look like? What is the actual trouble you are having with it? Please explain.

Comment: I am able to get the data in json format (As given above). I want to read the values from the obtained json. for ex. value of total_cases (5038) to be shown on a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an Access Violation because you are using `TJSONObject` incorrectly.

All of the JSON values you are trying to read are not immediate children of the top level object of the JSON hierarchy, where you are expecting, so `GetValue()` returns a `nil` pointer, and then your code crashes when it tries to read the `Value` property using that `nil` pointer.

The values you want are several levels deeper in the JSON hierarchy. The top level object contains a child named `countrydata`, which is an array of objects. The values you want are children of the 1st object in that array.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonRoot: TJSONValue;
  jsonObj: TJSONObject;
  jsonArr: TJSONArray;
  tokenRequest: TRESTRequest;
  tokenResponse: TRESTResponse;
  tokenClient: TRESTClient;
begin
  tokenClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  try
    tokenClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=PK';

    tokenRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(tokenClient);
    tokenRequest.Client := tokenClient;

    tokenResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(tokenClient);
    tokenRequest.Response := tokenResponse;

    tokenRequest.Execute;

    jsonRoot := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(tokenResponse.JSONText);
    try
      jsonObj := jsonRoot as TJSONObject;
      jsonArr := jsonObj.GetValue('countrydata') as TJSONArray;
      jsonObj := jsonArr.Items[0] as TJSONObject;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalCases => ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_cases').Value);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalRecovered=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_recovered').Value);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalDeaths=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_deaths').Value);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('TotoalNewCases=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_new_cases_today').Value);
    finally
      jsonRoot.Free;
    end;
  finally
    tokenClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`TRESTResponse.RootElement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.RootElement) and [`TRESTResponse.JSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONValue) properties instead of calling `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` manually:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonObj: TJSONObject;
  jsonArr: TJSONArray;
  tokenRequest: TRESTRequest;
  tokenResponse: TRESTResponse;
  tokenClient: TRESTClient;
begin
  tokenClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  try
    tokenClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=PK';

    tokenRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(tokenClient);
    tokenRequest.Client := tokenClient;

    tokenResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(tokenClient);
    tokenRequest.Response := tokenResponse;
    tokenResponse.RootElement := 'countrydata';

    tokenRequest.Execute;

    jsonArr := tokenResponse.JSONValue as TJSONArray;
    jsonObj := jsonArr.Items[0] as TJSONObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalCases => ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_cases').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalRecovered=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_recovered').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotalDeaths=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_deaths').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('TotoalNewCases=> ' + jsonObj.GetValue('total_new_cases_today').Value);
  finally
    tokenClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau but both codes gives the following errors. **[dcc32 Error] CovidMain.pas(103): E2149 Class does not have a default property** and **[dcc32 Error] CovidMain.pas(103): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type**. Do I need to add some uses classes or something is missing??

Comment: I am using Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1, does that have any issue regarding this code??

Comment: @AmjadTabassum try using `jsonArr.Items[]` instead of `jsonArr[]`. I have updated my examples.